# Pandas modified rolling average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Below is my outlier detection code in pandas. I am doing rolling over window of 15, what I want is to do over window of 5 where this window is based on the day of week of the centered date i.e. if the centre is Monday take 2 backwards monday and 2 forward monday. Rolling doesn't have any support for this. How to do?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

dates = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2023-12-31', freq='D')

prices1 = np.random.randint(10, 100, size=len(dates))
prices2 = np.random.randint(20, 120, size=len(dates)).astype(float)

data = {'Date': dates, 'Price1': prices1, 'Price2': prices2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

r = df.Price1.rolling(window=15, center=True)
price_up, price_low = r.mean() + 2 * r.std(), r.mean()  -  2 * r.std()

mask_upper = df['Price1'] > price_up
mask_lower = df['Price1'] < price_low

df.loc[mask_upper, 'Price1'] = r.mean()
df.loc[mask_lower, 'Price1'] = r.mean()
```

Comment: Do you only want to include Mondays if the center is a Monday? Or all days between them?

Comment: For Monday, include only Mondays.
Don't want to include anything in between.

Comment: I edited your example to have a reproducible seed and ensure having floats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option using a [`groupby.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rolling.html) and the [`dayofweek`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html) as grouper to ensure only using the identical days in the rolling:

```
r = (df.set_index('Date')
       .groupby(df['Date'].dt.dayofweek.values) # avoid index alignment
       .rolling(f'{5*7}D', center=True)
       ['Price1']
    )
avg = r.mean().set_axis(df.index) # restore correct index
std = r.std().set_axis(df.index)
price_up, price_low = avg + 2 * std, avg  -  2 * std

mask_upper = df['Price1'] > price_up
mask_lower = df['Price1'] < price_low

df.loc[mask_upper, 'Price1'] = avg
df.loc[mask_lower, 'Price1'] = avg
```

Example output:

```
          Date  Price1  Price2
0   2022-01-01    54.0    86.0
1   2022-01-02    57.0   117.0
2   2022-01-03    74.0    32.0
3   2022-01-04    77.0    35.0
4   2022-01-05    77.0    53.0
..         ...     ...     ...
725 2023-12-27    44.0    37.0
726 2023-12-28    60.0    65.0
727 2023-12-29    30.0   116.0
728 2023-12-30    53.0    82.0
729 2023-12-31    10.0    42.0

[730 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Yes you can simply the code if you assume a range index and all dates. I tried to provide a robust solution that works in a generic case without those assumptions